# Subtract rows from another row

Tags: sql, firebird

I need to subtract others rows from one specific row. I can get data in rows with two column (Amount, Type) or in one row and four columns (Type 1, Type 2, ...).

At the and I need data in first form.

Example:

[image]

```
select
    "Celkem",
    "Typ"
from
(
    pretty long SQL query
) X
```

and because I have pretty long query, I would like to avoid joining the same query. Is here any way how can I achieve my goal? With `case` construction on something similar?

Comment: What does "OR" mean when describing a table layout?

Comment: In my query I can get data in both that forms, but at the end, I need to have the right side of image

Comment: I don't understand your question. The only difference on the right side is the amount for `Salary` but the form is identical. You don't explain where the difference in amount comes from.

Comment: It is substract from others rows, it is in Title and in the text

Answer (score 1):

Input 2 columns, output 2 columns.

I used subquery:

```
Update Tablename
SET Amount = Amount - (SELECT SUM(Amount)
                        FROM TableName
                        WHERE Type <> 'Salary'
                        )
WHERE Type = 'Salary'
```

There might be some syntax issue, not very familiar with `firebird`.

Comment: That's pretty good idea, I have to save data in table at the end and this could be work! I will definitely try it, thanks!

Comment: Is the syntax correct if not can you update it please, so that if someone comes again for this question, it will be easier. And happy to help. Thanks for the upvote.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Firebird supports `pivot` or `unpivot`.  You can do what you want with the second layout and some rather complex `case` statements:

```
select (case when n.n = 1 then VAT
             when n.n = 2 then Salary - VAT - Social - Care
             when n.n = 3 then Social
             when n.n = 4 then Care
        end) as Amount,
       (case when n.n = 1 then 'VAT'
             when n.n = 2 then 'Salary'
             when n.n = 3 then 'Social'
             when n.n = 4 then 'Care'
        end) as Amount
from flattable t cross join
     (select 1 as n from RDB$DATABASE union all
      select 2 as n from RDB$DATABASE union all
      select 3 as n from RDB$DATABASE union all
      select 4 as n from RDB$DATABASE
     ) n;
```

Answer (score 0):

Given data with 2 columns you can use `sum(Amount) over()` to get the total sum and subtract the Salary value from it.

```
select 
    type,
    (case when type = 'Salary'
    then Amount - (sum(Amount) over () - Amount)
    else Amount end)
from (
    pretty long SQL query
) X
```

Comment: Window functions (`over()`) are introduced in Firebird 3, which hasn't been released yet.